# Having trouble with adding an ArrayList to an ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, arraylist

```
public class Tabel {
    private static int dimension;

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> tabel;


    public Tabel(int dimension) {

        Tabel.dimension = dimension;

        for (int i=0;i<Tabel.dimension*Tabel.dimension;i++) {
           tabel.add(new ArrayList<Character>());
        }

     }
}
```

When I try to debug (eclipse ide) I get a lot of weird "errors" or at the very least I encounter something I consider unexpected.

The private static int does not appear in the "variables" section of debug.

I get a `NullPointerException` on `tabel.add(...)` but when I watch the debug, it enters the `for` once, does not add anything in the table because when I hit "next" instead of jumping to the closing braces it jumps out of the function.

If I comment the `.add` it works so that's the problem (I think). Is my syntax wrong ? or should I post more code ?

Comment: Just a note: Having a `static` variable that gets initialized by the constructor seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Keppil This is a "thin version" I have a boolean that makes sure it only happens once, I know it's not the best way but I have no other idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tabel` is not initialized, so it is null.

Change

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> tabel;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> tabel = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
```

Or better:

```
private List<ArrayList<Character>> tabel = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
```

since this does not tie `tabel` to `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the `private` List. Do the following:

```
private List<ArrayList<Character>> tabel = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have trouble understanding that level of nesting too.

It's better to refer to List rather than ArrayList.  Unless you need a method in the concrete class, it makes your program more flexible to refer to the interface and the methods in the interface.

Create a class (1) that has a field defined as a List of Character.  Set the field to a new ArrayList in the constructor.

Create another class (2) that has a field defined as a List of class (1).  Set the field to a new ArrayList in the constructor.

Create another class (3) that has a field defined as a List of class (2).  Set the field to a new ArrayList in the constructor.

Since you understand what you're doing, you can give these 3 classes more meaningful names.